# Change default calendar on Exchange-2010 mailbox

Tags: calendar, exchange-2010, shared-mailbox

I have a mailbox with 3 calendars (Exchange2010 / OL2007). Is it possible to change the default-calendar for this mailbox?

Problem is that all meeting-request will be placed in the default-calender but should go to a different calender.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved by following these steps:

1. Go to *File » Account settings* in 2010. For 2007, *Tools » Account Settings*.
2. Navigate to the *Data* tab
3. There you can find the list of calendars which you use (ensure that your calendars are present at Internet, published calendars section)
4. Choose your calendar and choose *Set as default*.
5. Close and restart your Outlook

Comment: Thanks a lot, but your suggestion does not work for me.

I have 3 calendars on one Mailbox which are not shared (User map this mailbox into their own Outlook-profile)

I would need a way to change the default-calendar within this mailbox.

I have already checked with MFCMAPI but there I could not find a suitable setting/value to change the default calendar.